# Are there infinite triples of consecutive integers whose numbers of factors are increasing?

Tags: number-theory

We know that there exists infinite numbers of integers $n$ such that $d(n)<d(n+1)$, where $d(n)$ is the number of positive divisors of $n$.
Question: are there infinite numbers of integers $n$ such that $d(n)<d(n+1)<d(n+2)$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $p>3$ be a prime such that $2p-1$ and $4p^2+2p+1$ are also prime${}^1$, i.e., $$\tag1p\in\{7,19,31,97,139,157,199,439,601,727,829,997,1069,1279,\ldots\}.$$ Let $n=(2p)^3-1$. Then 
$$ d(n)=d((2p-1)(4p^2+2p+1))=4,$$
$$ d(n+1)=d(2^3p^3)=16,$$
$$ d(n+2)=d((2p+1)(4p^2-2p+1)).$$
One verifies that  $\gcd(2p+1,4p^2-2p+1)=\gcd(2p+1,-2p+2)=\gcd(2p+1,3)=3$.

If one of $2p+1, 4p^2-2p+1$ is a power of $3$, this makes $n+2=3^ka$ with $k\ge 8$ (because this happens for none of the $p<\frac{3^7+1}2$ listed in $(1)$) and $a>1$ a non-multiple of $3$ (because $2p+1\nmid 4p^2-2p+1$, it cannot happen that both $2p+1, 4p^2-2p+1$ are powers of $3$). We conclude $d(n+2)=(k+1)d(a)>16$, as desired.

If none of $2p+1, 4p^2-2p+1$ is a power of $3$, this makes $n+2=3^kab$ with $k\ge 2$ and $a,b>1$ coprime non-multiples of $3$. We conclude $d(n+2)=(k+1)d(a)d(b)\ge 16$ with equality only if both $\frac{2p+1}3$ and $\frac{4p^2-2p+1}3$ are prime. But this cannot happen: For $p=7$, we have $4p^2-2p+1=3\cdot 23\cdot 139$ and in all other cases, we have $p\not\equiv 0\pmod 7$, $2p-1\not\equiv 0\pmod 7$, $4p^2+2p+1\not\equiv 0\pmod 7$, hence $p\equiv 3,5,6\pmod 7$. In the first case, $2p+1\equiv 0\pmod 7$, in the other cases $4p^2-2p+1\equiv 0\pmod 7$. We conclude that $d(n+2=>16$ as desired.

Therefore, there are infinitely many solutions to $d(n)<d(n+1)<d(n+2)$ provided the set of primes in $(1)$ is infinite. Unfortunately, it is already only conjectured that the (larger) set of primes such that $2p-1$ is also prime is infinite. *Heuristically,* the number of such $p$ should be
$$\sim \sum_n\frac1{\ln( n)\ln(2n-1)\ln(4n^2+2n+1)}\sim\sum\frac1{\ln^3n}=\infty.$$

---

${}^1$ Actually, $4p^2+2p+1$ need not be prime; $d(4p^2+2p+1)\le 7$ and $7\nmid 4p^2+2p+1$ would be good enough.

Comment: Given that $4\frac{p+1}{2}=2p+2=n+3$, why are you claiming $d(n+2)=d(n+3)$?

Comment: @J.G. I reworked my answer completely - my original had the mistake you noticed (and after correction would have turned into *TonyK*'s answer). Apparently, this answer also makes use of Sophie Germain-like primes (with sign change) with some additional condition. In the end, the additional conditions in *TonyK*'s answer are certainly "milder" (some expression has at least five divisors as opposed to some expression is prime). Then again, it is not even knwon whether infinitely many Germain primes (or theri  minus-counterparts) exist ...

Answer (score 1):

Let $p>3$ be any prime such that $2p-1$ is also prime. Then $2p-1$, being prime, has two factors; and $2p$ has four factors. So the triple $(2p-1,2p,2p+1)$ satisfies your condition as long as $d(2p+1)>4$.

$2p+1$ is divisible by $3$ (because the preceding two integers aren't). So $2p+1=3q$ for some $q$; and this number has at least six factors unless $q$ is prime or is itself a multiple of $3$. If $q$ is a multiple of $3$, then $2p+1=r\cdot 3^k$ for some $k\ge 2$ and some $r$ not divisible by $3$, and $d(2p+1)=(k+1)d(r)$. This is $\ge 5$ unless $r=1$ and $k \le 3$; but these two cases (i.e. $2p+1=9$ or $27$) are ruled out because $8$ is not twice a prime, and $25$ is not prime.

Hence if $p>3$ and

- $p$ is prime;
- $2p-1$ is prime;
- $(2p+1)/3$ is composite,

then $(2p-1,2p,2p+1)$ satisfies your conditions.

Such triples are easy to find, but it is beyond my capabilities to prove that there are an infinite number of them. I suspect that it is beyond anyone's capabalities at our current state of knowledge.

Comment: Cf. http://oeis.org/A005382 for only the condition that $p$ and $2p-1$ are prime. These are similar (but apparently unnamed) to Sophie Germain primes, and it is *conjectured* that there are infinitely many such primes (for both types). Assuming that, it is indeed at least *plausible* that it is not the case that  $\frac{2p+1}3$ is prime for almost all of them ...